# Switching EF Model from SSCE 4.0 to SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2008, entity-framework, sql-server-ce

This is for a new project which will start on the desktop with the option to scale to multiple users on SQL Server 2008 R2 or SQL Server 2012

I'm looking for some real world experience, tips, gotchas etc.

**UPDATE** - Ideally would prefer to switch in runtime via a config entry.

**UPDATE 2** - Are there any pattern(s) which can be used here?

**UPDATE 3** - the SQL SERVER 2008 db schema is already in prod use, so cannot start with ssce model code first and progress from there

Comment: Do you need to switch in runtime?

Comment: What's your use case for SSCE 4.0?  We did several spikes comparing SQL2008 R2 Express vs. SSCE 4.0 as a local DB connecting to a main server and SQL Express won hands down.  The crux of the issue was that we already had a schema and translating it to a DB engine with many, many gaps made the cost far outweigh the benefit.

Comment: cannot install sqlexpress as the pc footprint/req have to be kept to the min

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The theory

**EDMX**

In case of EDMX you need at least two SSDL files. One for SQL server and one for SQL Server CE. The reason is that SSDL file describes database including database types. Some types in SQL Server CE are different. For example SQL server CE doesn't support `NVARCHAR(max)` and you must use `NTEXT` instead. SSDL also contains information about provider manifest so even if your column types and names are exactly same you still need to SSDLs to differ provider manifests.

If your tables and names in both databases will be same you can use same MSL (CSDL must be the same). Working with two SSDLs is much harder because it either means two EDMXs and some manual synchronization of changes or single EDMX and some script which will extract second SSDL or maintaining whole mapping manually in XML files. Entity framework VS designer is not prepared for this type of usage.

**Code-first**

Code first provides much more simplified situation because you don't have to deal with SSDL. SSDL is created automatically when your application starts based on provider defined in connection string and mapping defined in your model.

Even code first can have problems when it comes to different data types in SQL Server and SQL Server CE. As and example we can again use large strings.

### The practice

The theory says it is possible. The practice says it can be much more challenging. SQL Server and SQL Server CE are different database servers with different features and performance. SQL Server provides much more features and some of these features will not work on SQL Server CE (views, sql procedures) at all (you mentioned you already have schema for SQL Server) or will be much slower. Once you meet this limitations you will either have to branch your development for separate support on SQL Server and SQL Server CE or you will have to make compromises.

Answer (score 1):

Actually EF Models are different for SSCE 4.0 and SQL Server, so you will need to make some "[facade](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern)".
Another good option could be EF Code First where you will need only to change the connection strings.

Comment: I would think only the SSDL/MSL are different...no?

Answer (score 0):

You can use code first to generate the tables in SqlExpress. Then in server explorer you can access the sqlexpress mdf. Right click and click Publish to Provider. Use the script to file option. The tables and all can be exported as a sql script. The sql script can then run against Sql Server 2008 to create the tables in your sql server db.

Comment: I'm curious...did you downvote the respondent for not reading your mind? If the answer was useful in the context of the question as worded at the time, I don't think that failure to anticipate your unstated needs warrants a downvote.

Comment: Thats what i am wondering to. The original title had to do with migrating from CE to R2 and that what i understood the question to be.